# How to add the variable (column) name before each row string in the column

Tags: r, paste

I would like to add the column name to each character string in the column. Here is a small data frame to use.

```
df <-structure(list(CoA = c("Baton Rouge", "Birmingham", "Chattanooga", 
"Columbia", "Houston"), CoB = c("Haddonfield, NJ", "Haddonfield, NJ", 
"Philadelphia, PA", "Hackensack, NJ", "Princeton, NJ"), CoC = c("St. Louis, Missouri", 
"Kansas City, Missouri", "Jefferson City, Missouri", "Belleville, Illinois", 
"Overland Park, Kansas")), .Names = c("CoA", "CoB", "CoC"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the following, but R recycles through the object company and the object df.

```
company <- colnames(df)
new <- sapply(df, function(x) paste(company, x, sep = ", "))
```

This is what I want, but for all columns:

```
paste(colnames(df[1]), df$CoA, sep = ", ")
[1] "CoA, Baton Rouge" "CoA, Birmingham"  "CoA, Chattanooga" "CoA, Columbia"    "CoA, Houston"
```

I tried various regular expressions and got nowhere. How do I get `sapply` to do this paste operation on each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
mx <- sapply(colnames(df),function(name){ paste(name,df[,name],sep=", ")})

> mx
     CoA                CoB                     CoC                            
[1,] "CoA, Baton Rouge" "CoB, Haddonfield, NJ"  "CoC, St. Louis, Missouri"     
[2,] "CoA, Birmingham"  "CoB, Haddonfield, NJ"  "CoC, Kansas City, Missouri"   
[3,] "CoA, Chattanooga" "CoB, Philadelphia, PA" "CoC, Jefferson City, Missouri"
[4,] "CoA, Columbia"    "CoB, Hackensack, NJ"   "CoC, Belleville, Illinois"    
[5,] "CoA, Houston"     "CoB, Princeton, NJ"    "CoC, Overland Park, Kansas"
```

Note that `sapply` returns a matrix; if you want a `data.frame` just do `as.data.frame(mx)`

**Explanation:**

`sapply` applies a function to each element of the vector/list passed in the first argument `X` (in this case we pass `colnames(df)`).
The function that is applied to each element is passed through argument `FUN`.
In this case we pass the following function to `FUN`:

```
function(name){ 
   paste(name,df[,name],sep=", ")
   # equivalent to return(paste(name,df[,name],sep=", "))
}
```

this function is called for each element of `colname(df)` and each element is passed as first argument (i.e. argument `name`).
So, using `name` (remember is one column name) we select a column of `df`, we prepend the column name using `paste` function and we return the resulting vector of strings.
The rest is left to `sapply` function, that automatically bind each resulting vector into one matrix (because `simplify=TRUE` by default, otherwise a list of vectors would be returned as it happens using `lapply`)

**EDIT** :

As correctly pointed out by @hadley, the outcome of `sapply` with `simplify=TRUE` is not always the same (for example it changes if you have just one row or one column only).
So this is a safer solution :

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(colnames(df),
                            function(name){ paste(name,df[,name],sep=", ")},
                            simplify=F))

> df2
               CoA                   CoB                           CoC
1 CoA, Baton Rouge  CoB, Haddonfield, NJ      CoC, St. Louis, Missouri
2  CoA, Birmingham  CoB, Haddonfield, NJ    CoC, Kansas City, Missouri
3 CoA, Chattanooga CoB, Philadelphia, PA CoC, Jefferson City, Missouri
4    CoA, Columbia   CoB, Hackensack, NJ     CoC, Belleville, Illinois
5     CoA, Houston    CoB, Princeton, NJ    CoC, Overland Park, Kansas
```

Comment: that is excellent.  Would you mind adding a short explanation?  I am unsure about "name" as you use it.

Comment: If you want to keep as a data frame, better to use `lapply()`, not `sapply()`.

Comment: @lawyeR: added an explanation

Comment: @hadley: lapply would return a list of vectors hence we still need to call `do.call(cbind,...)` to create a `data.frame`. I find `sapply` version shorter...

Comment: @digEmAll `sapply()` is dangerous because you never know what the output will be. `as.data.frame(lapply(...))` is safer and the same length as the equivalent call with `sapply()`.

Comment: @hadley: that's a fair point. Probably, the best solution is to use `sapply` with `simplify=F` since in this case it creates a named list so `as.data.frame` automatically gets the correct column names...

Comment: @digEmAll `sapply` with `simplify = F` is just a verbose way to type `lapply()`. When writing a function you almost never want to use `sapply()` because you don't know what you're going to get. Instead use `lapply()` or `vapply()`.

Comment: @hadley: yep, the difference between sapply with simplify=F and lapply is the parameter USE.NAMES; if you set it to false then sapply=lapply. However, that "ability" to use names of sapply is useful in this case since it creates a named list instead of a simple list and as.data.frame returns the desired data.frame with the correct column names...

Comment: @digEmAll `lapply()` always preserves names.

Comment: @hadley: well, not in this case...try to replace sapply with lapply in the code above and you'll see a df2 with column names like "c..CoA..Baton.Rouge....CoA..Birmingham....CoA..Chattanooga.." etc..